# SQLite and LINQ to SQL - Problems with DataContext and database creation

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, linq-to-sql

I write a .NET application in C# which is using SQLite database. And I want to use LINQ to SQL as ORM in order to work with database. So two nuget packages are installed in my project for that reason: [System.Data.SQLite Core (x86/x64)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) and [System.Data.SQLite LINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Linq/).

Here is some of simplified code from my app:

```
[Table]
public class Entity
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, CanBeNull = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class EntityDataContent : DataContext
{
    public EntityDataContent(IDbConnection connection) : base(connection)
    {
    }

    public Table<Entity> Entities
    {
        get { return GetTable<Entity>(); }
    }
}
```

To get data from the database I use the following code:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=db.sqlite; Version=3;");
using (EntityDataContent dataContext = new EntityDataContent(connection))
{
    return dataContext.Entities.ToList();
}
```

It won't work because there are no database and tables in it. So at first they should be created:

```
using (EntityDataContent dataContext = new EntityDataContent(connectionString))
{
    if (!dataContext.DatabaseExists())
    {
        dataContext.CreateDatabase();
    }
}
```

And here goes the problem. This code throws SQLiteException with message:

```
SQL logic error or missing database
near "DATABASE": syntax error
```

All is because database provider tries to create database with help of `CREATE DATABASE`, but there is no such operation in SQLite. File is already a database by itself.

So I suppose that my `DataContext` uses default database provider instead of SQLite implementation provided by corresponding nuget package. I can't figure out how to fix this and where can be the problem. Have you any suggestions?